# Clearing cache for [pagespeed-insights]?

Tags: caching, pagespeed-insights

We have a site that a client uploaded a couple very large images into a menu, and it killed the load speed for the site on PageSpeed Insights.  I went in and completely deleted the image from the media library and replaced it with an optimized image, yet the site is still recieving the same low score for those large images, even though they no longer exist on the site.  If you click on the URL of the image with PageSpeed Insights, you get a 404 error, since it doesn't exist anymore.   Why is it still showing in PageSpeed Insights?  Is there a cache that needs to be cleared?  This has been going on for over a week now.

Comment: care to share the URL, PSI does not cache so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: https://commonwealthcommunitytrust.org/

Comment: Here is the image that PSI says is causing the biggest slowdown: https://commonwealthcommunitytrust.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/lady-in-wheelchair_Large.jpg .   Yet that image no longer exists on the server.

Comment: The image does still exist on the server, you are being redirect to a 404 page for some reason, open it in internet explorer, purple wheelchair, checked shirt, trees in background

Comment: Yet here is the strange thing... after pulling that image up in IE, hit CTRL F5 to hard refresh the image.  It's gone.  I physically went into the server and removed the image from the folder last week.

Comment: Have you just changed servers by any chance?

Comment: No.  been on the same server for over a year

Answer (score 0):

You are using [WP-super-cache plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) and something has gone wrong.

Disable the plugin and then look for the folder where it caches images (or just clear the cache within the plugin). Delete the folder.

You may also need to change your NGINX directives as well as I have a feeling they are redirecting incorrectly and that is the cause of the strange behaviour.

I would then use a different plugin.

**Make sure to take a backup of the files and database first** as there appear to be a lot of complaints about the plugin breaking sites so be careful.

Comment: Here's what I did:  Disabled WP Supercache.  Deleted all cache folders using file manager, installed and activate WP Optimze (instead of WP Super Cache).  Initiated Preload of Cache.  Waited for caching to complete.   Re-ran PSI.  Same result.  any other ideas? (I do appreciate your recommendations)

Comment: Check your NGINX directives and see where they point. If this is an older site that you have inherited there could be overhang from other plugins. I am 99% certain a malfunctioning cache is the cause, the only other causes would be something wrong with DNS pointing to a second source but that is unlikely given how long the site has run, or that you are using some interesting CDN setup that gets piped through your server.